# What is the genre or type of music from Don't Starve?

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre, videogame-soundtrack

[The original soundtrack for Don't Starve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JK2q80luow)

I have heard the type of music before in other video games such as Contrast

[Contrast Soundtrack: Main Attraction](https://youtu.be/Y8UhcfxHKW4?t=677)

and also in the Darkmoon faire area in World of Wacraft

[Carousel Music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqj-p6zEgy8)

The common theme is the inclusion of elements of carnivals even throughout the art in the video games.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me the genre or type of music this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, this genre is actually called "carnival music" (also "circus music" or occasionally "carousel music").  To get closer to this particular sound, try adding the modifier "dark" or "creepy" (i.e. "creepy carnival").  It's typically late Victorian era dance music played on circus instruments, such as the calliope organ.

Your second selection, although very related in sound, could alternately be described as a ["Valse Musette"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lObuzBLp9qk), a Parisian version of waltz music typically played by street musicians, either organ grinders or accordionists.  If you don't necessarily want the carnival associations, you could search for either this or "Bal Musette", a more general term for the Parisian dance music of the 1880s.

If it has vocals, this genre is called "dark cabaret," as found in the Beatles' ["Mr Kite"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LCclVtFR6o) and many of Tom Waits' [best-known songs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkj_ov_0LA4).